# How to update the values in my components onces the query cache is sucessfully updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a list of 3 data "cards" which are being sucessfully pulled from my api using react query. It is all being set via this custom hook I have written which uses a mutation and the `queryclient.setQueryData` hook.

Within my React component I am then using another custom hook which uses `queryClient.getQueryData` to load in the data from my query cache.

When I want to delete one of these data cards, I run a mutation to update the data in the API (which is called from a sub-component) and on success, I use the `queryClient.setQueryData` hook to update the query cache.

Using the react-query dev tools, I can see that it is being sucessfully updated in the cache but my components do not update until I navigate away/back to the page so that they call for the data from the cache again.

Is there a way to notify the component that it should reload the data from the cache, or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

> Within my React component I am then using another custom hook which uses queryClient.getQueryData to load in the data from my query cache.

`queryClient.getQueryData` does *not* create a subscription to the cached data, only `useQuery` does this.

> sucessfully updated in the cache but my components do not update

this is because you have not created a subscription, see above.

> Is there a way to notify the component that it should reload the data from the cache, or anything like that?

always call `useQuery` to retrieve data from the cache, then it will be notified of all changes.